# Upgrading geth after EIP150 Hardfork

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, bug, blockchain-fork, eip150

Due to the recent EIP150 Hardfork in Ethereum my Geth node needed an upgrade from v1.4.10 to v1.4.18:

```
cd ethereum
wget "https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/download/v1.4.18/geth-linux-amd64-1.4.18-ef9265d0.tar.gz"
tar -zxvf geth-linux-amd64-1.4.18-ef9265d0.tar.gz
pkill geth
mv geth geth.old
cp geth-linux-amd64-1.4.18-ef9265d0/geth ./geth
nohup ./geth --rpc --testnet &
```

After launching geth seems to get stuck processing same block all the time:

```
E1025 10:36:10.603692 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:10.603739 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
E1025 10:36:16.271015 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:16.271061 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
E1025 10:36:18.351420 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:18.351452 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
E1025 10:36:18.895763 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:18.895794 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
E1025 10:36:19.900784 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:19.900810 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
E1025 10:36:20.094734 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1808134 (0x53b51f327d1844b2c1abc0f9440eae479636fd6c6e88101a4af9d3ea90cdc547)
E1025 10:36:20.094771 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (2831504 / 2838374)
```

Any ideas why it does like this? How can I fix it? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug after recent hard fork.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3183

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding all blockchain from scratch has fixed it, but I would have preferred a faster solution. Any ideas?

On another node, I got a similar result after upgrading:

```
E1027 08:05:06.621020 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1813322 (0x2612c6b92ced0ae0d7cff7a303f47eab31600df326dfa6b131f4f05ca5df69fd)
E1027 07:59:03.702864 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (216232 / 219832)
E1027 07:59:03.702699 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1813322 (0x2612c6b92ced0ae0d7cff7a303f47eab31600df326dfa6b131f4f05ca5df69fd)
E1027 07:57:56.040060 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (216232 / 219832)
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error for block `1809368` on the testnet. This was a sync from scratch. Left it overnight and it's solid errors now.